# Executing jquery methods without eval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have repeating code of `$("#id").addClass('disabled');` and `$("#li-hzd").removeClass('disabled');` in my code for multiple ids in multiple functions. So I am trying to write some generic routine something like,

```
function toggleClass(id,classname,action){
    $("#"+ id") +"." + classname+"("+action+") 
}
```

which can be called something like,

```
toggleClass(id,'addClass','disabled');
toggleClass(id,'removeClass','disabled');
```

I believe something can be done using eval() but I also read it's bad practice to use eval. So any idea how to accomplish ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also get the jQuery methods by using [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors).

```
function toggleClass(id, action, classname){
    $("#"+ id)[action](classname) 
}

toggleClass(id,'addClass','disabled');
toggleClass(id,'removeClass','disabled');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can **access object properties via [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) `[]`**:

```
function toggleClass(id, classname, action) {
    $("#" + id)[classname](action) 
}
```

---

Side note: You seem to have gotten the naming of the parameters `classname` and `action` wrong. Should probably be the other way round to make more sense! The function name should be the `action` and the class name should be the `classname`. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using addClass and removeClass,use can just use toggleClass which adds the class name if not present else removes it

so change your toggleclass method to the following

```
function toggleClass(id,classname){
    $("#"+ id).toggleClass(classname) 
}
```